# Azure Mobile Service javascript SDK does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a simple Azure Mobile Service backend written in C# which has a login functionality at `/api/CustomLogin`. The following function is a simple login test I made in Javascript for my web app which accesses these data:

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
    URL,
    API_KEY
);

function tryLogin(username, password) {
    client.invokeApi("CustomLogin", {
        body: {
            username: username,
            password: password
        },
        method: "post"
    }).done(function (results) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(results));
    }, function (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err);
    });
}
```

This works fine on Chrome 37 and Internet Explorer 11, and returns a JSON object with the correct statuscode and an authentication token. However, when I run this test on Firefox 32 it returns an empty object `{}` instead, which means I don't receive the user information. I am using the Azure Mobile Services SDK from http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.2.min.js.

I have tested this both on localhost and on a deployed webpage (also hosted at Azure websites), using both http and https (provided by Azure), and this works on Chrome and Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox.

Other functions from Mobile Service API work in Firefox, for example

```
var peopleTable = client.getTable('people');
var query = peopleTable.read().done(function (results) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(results));
}, function (err) {
    alert("Error: " + err);
});
```

This leads me to suspect that there is a problem with `invokeApi` but I cannot understand why this problem only occurs in Firefox.

Comment: There was a bug in the invokeAPI path that it errors out if no Content-Type was sent in the response. It could be FF was more sensitive to that bug. Can you try updating to 1.2.5.js (or 1.2.5.min.js) and see if the issue still happens?

Comment: Okay, I have updated to 1.2.5.js and the problem persists. I added a few console.logs to the invokeAPI method, and I can see that in Firefox the response is encoded in XML instead of in JSON as in Chrome, which is why it fails to convert it to a JSON object in FF. Do you know how I can force the response to be JSON across all browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that in the .NET backend, you get content negotiation enabled by default - the client can ask the service which content types it "prefers" to respond (via the `Accept` headers). In most browsers, the client request will say that it "accepts" everything, and the "preferred" formatter used in the .NET backend is one that converts objects into JSON on the wire.

Firefox, however, sends an `Accept` header that says that it prefers to receive **XML**. The backend will happily oblige, and your API call will receive the XML response sent by the service. You can even look at the `responseText` property of the response and see it there.

```
function tryLogin(username, password) {
    client.invokeApi("CustomLogin", {
        body: {
            username: username,
            password: password
        },
        method: "post"
    }).done(function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }, function (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err);
    });
}
```

Now, if you don't want to deal with XML (and I wouldn't blame you for that) you have two options: in the server side, remove the XML formatter from the list of formatters that the server has. On the WebApiConfig, this line should do the trick:

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Or you can override the Accept header sent by firefox, by passing it directly when you call the API:

```
function tryLogin(username, password) {
    client.invokeApi("CustomLogin", {
        body: {
            username: username,
            password: password
        },
        method: "post",
        headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }
    }).done(function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response.result));
    }, function (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err);
    });
}
```

Once you do that, you'll have the result of your API in the `result` property of the argument to your success callback.

Comment: I ended up adding the headers: { Accept: 'application/json' } to my javascript calls and it works perfectly!